# Cannot find Velocity property of a Rigibody2D component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi you know I can't make my character move in unity, because c# doesn't accet word "velocity". Help me solve this problem please.

```
public class MarioController : MonoBehaviour 
{
        public float maxSpeed=10f;
        bool facingRight=true;

    void Start ()
    {}

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

    rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

        if (move > 0 && !facingRight)
            Flip ();

    else if (move < 0 && facingRight)
            Flip ();
    }

    void Flip ()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;

    }

}
```

Comment: C# has no problem with using `velocity` as an identifier. My guess is that whatever type `rigidbody2D` is (we can't tell from the code you've shown us) doesn't have a member called `velocity`.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I believe it does. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: Do you have access to more information than we do? Where is `rigidbody2D` even declared?

Comment: I think the problem lies with the `rigidbody2D`. I think you need to declare the variable and set in the `Start`method. Like [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html).

Comment: Also note that we wouldn't have to do as much guesswork if the question included the exact error message.

Comment: `Content acceptance` is a bit of a curveball, OP. Rephrase the title.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is **not** that C# doesn't "accept" the property called Velocity, your problem is that you never declared the rigibody2D variable. Typically, you'd something like this:

If you're using Unity3D 5.3 there's a property that you can use to flip the sprite, it should have better performance:

```
public class MarioController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float maxSpeed=10f;
    bool facingRight=true;
    Rigibody2D rigibody2D;
    SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    void Start()
    {
        rigibody2D = GetComponent<Rigibody2D>(); //get the reference to the Rigibody2D component of this GameObject
spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>(); //get the reference to the SpriteRenderer component of this GameObject
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

        if (move > 0 && !facingRight)
            Flip (facingRight);
        else if (move < 0 && facingRight)
            Flip (facingRight);
    }

    void Flip (bool flip)
    {
         facingRight = !flip;
         spriteRenderer.flipX = flip;
        //facingRight = !facingRight;
        //Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        //theScale.x *= -1;
        //transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
}
```